# How to store data in online and access using android app

Tags: android, web-services

This is my first app which i am doing to create.I want to create a quiz app which will store all questions online and when user uses the app, they will get questions which are fetched from the server.

I dont want to storage data offline.

I want to know how to store data on the server.

If this can be done free of cost plz specify that also.
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use parse.com for the storage. When the app is used retrieve the questions from the backend and display on the screen.
You can learn more about parse [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide)

Tutorial to start with [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-cloud-backend-android-app-using-parse/)

I am providing some part of the code to retrieve from server and display in an listview.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // If there are questions, get all to display
            for (ParseObject post : postList) {
                Question q= new Question(post.getObjectId(), post.getString("question"));
                posts.add(q);
            }
            ((ArrayAdapter<Question>) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As i came to know that parse.com is retiring on 28 jan 2017 now can you suggest me any other site which will provide me free cloud storage and which is also best. I learnt about parse from you link and did a great progress in that but now forcefully need to change

Comment: Use https://backendless.com/. There is also a migration guide to migrate from parse to backendless. `https://backendless.com/parse-to-backendless-migration-guide/`

Comment: Is backendless.com similar to parse? I mean the coding part in the app. Is firebase better than the above said??

Comment: Can you plz suggest me a tutorial for querying in my app to read data from backendless,write into it and retrieve a partcular row from it

Answer (score 0):

If you want fetch data from server. try follow one of the way below.

1. Create web api method using server side programming like( [MVC web
   api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) C# or [PHP web service](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php) etc,.)
2. Store Question as json in the db , save it into app and read the
   json file and show questions to the user.

Comment: May u plz share a link from where i can learn about these. It will be helpful for me...

Comment: Please find the links. [MVC web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api)   [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php) .